# Anonymous tarballs

Tags: tar, gnu-tar

Tar encodes my user name into the tarball. Can I force it to make a fully anonymous tarball?

`--owner root` replaces only some instances of my user name. Adding `USER=root`: `USER=root tar c --owner root data` has no effect.

In short, I wish for:

```
echo hello world > data; tar c --owner root data | grep "$USER"
```

to **not** match.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What I was missing was `--group=root` in addition to `--owner=root`.

```
tar -c --{owner,group}=root
```

(possibly with an optional `--numeric-owner`) fully anonymizes the archive.

Comment: bash brace expansion `{a,b}` can be quite confusing. `--{owner,group}=root`
**will be expanded to `--owner=root --group=root`**

Comment: On macOS the command line options are `--uid 0` and `--gid 0`.

Comment: @Utkonos Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can use `--numeric-owner`, that will just put your UID (1000 or something similar on most systems) in the file. From  `man tar`:

```
 --numeric-owner
       always use numbers for user/group names
```

Comment: Thanks. It does the job, though only partly. Looks like cpio (which seems to always encode uids numerically) can anonymize its archives fully via the `--owner` switch.

Comment: IIRC --owner only works on extraction/pass-through. If I am wrong you can use cpio's `-H` option to directly write tar files.

Comment: It appears to work for `-o` too. I tried creating a simple archive with and without `--owner root:root` and then diffed their respective hexdumps. What changed were two two-byte sequence that little-endian-decoded to 0 and my `$UID` respectively.

Comment: @PSkocik That is interesting, I just checked `man cpio` and `cpio --help` and they both confirm what I commented before. Probably the source was updated, but the documentation wasn't (GNU cpio 2.11)